# Heating of a metal rod

Tags: thermal-conductivity

On heating a metal rod from one end ,after sometime it reaches a steady state. Is the temperature of the end directly receiving the heat is equivalent to the temperature of the heat source ? Even in the steady state as we move away from the heat source the temperature of the parts of the rod become  gradually cooler . Why don't the cooler areas make their temperature same as the end directly receiving heat ?

Answer (score 1):

The cooler areas are the areas that are continuously giving off heat into the atmosphere. This is the reason, the cooler areas do not achieve same temperature as the hotter area. They keep getting heat from the hotter area, but they keep giving off heat to the atmosphere as well.

Comment: Then why at first all portions in the rod  use the heat to raise their temperature   and then stop  ?

Comment: Let me ask you. What do you think is the steady state for this example? At steady state, what do you think are the temperatures across the rod ?

Comment: There is a uniform temperature gradient throughout the rod ... Are u asking me for particular values ?

Comment: Well u can consider them as 100 ( temp of source ) , 80 , 60 , 40 and 20 as we move away from the source ( in °C)

Comment: Okay, so few things. First of all, what happens in steady state will vary depending on temp of heat source, room temp and thermal conductivity of air as well as of the rod. And i do not just mean that the numbers will change . I mean whether or not there will be that kind of temp gradient through the rod will change. Also , in your example numbers, those numbers will not happen. The far part cannot have 20 celsius, ( assuming room temp is something over 20 ). Because, if it was at 20, it would start absorbing heat from air. No part of the rod can have steady state temp below the air temp.

Comment: When we  began heating the rod it's sections  took heat from source, used some  to raise the temperature, lost some  to the atmosphere and transmitted rest to the next part of the rod . When  steady state is reached  rate of absorption is same as the rate of emission. So the temperature gradient remains same . In other words why does it acquires the steady state after reaching a certain temperature gradient ? Is it some sort of physical equilibrium where the rate of emission is initially less than rate of absorption but then increases to become same ?

Comment: I am sorry for pestering u with questions I am really slow at understanding things maybe I am complicating them myself ...

Comment: It is not necessary that, in steady state, the temp gradient remains the same or even that there will be a temp gradient. That all depends on those factors i mentioned. For example, a possible  steady state could be, given that heating source has temp of say 100C, the entire rod has a uniform temperature, of  100C. Heat absorbed from source is same as heat emitted to air. Such a scenario will  occur when either air temp is high or conductivity of air is low.

Comment: My point is  there are many heat transfers going on when this experiment starts - source to rod, one part of rod to another, each part of rod to air. Each of these has a conductivity associated with it, and each has a temp differential across which the heat is transferred, leading to differing rates of heat transfer. And depending on those factors i mentioned, the final temperature profile of the rod can either be a gradient or a uniform temperature across the rod. To get the exact value, we will have to take some example numbers for all of those variables i mentioned.

Comment: So, whenever there is a temperature gradient between 2 adjoining parts of a rod, heat will be transferred from higher to lower part. The gradient will persist, if the amount of heat going from higher to lower part is balanced by the amount being lost to air by lower part. So, you can see whether this will happen depends on temp of higher part, temp of lower part , temp of air, conductivity between the 2 parts and conductivity of air. If the heat lost to air is low enough, either due to high air temp , or low air conductivity, then the gradient will not persist, otherwise it will.

Comment: Btw, i think the mods here do not like long to and fro discussions in comments.. They say, there are chatrooms here for such discussion. If you have any idea how to create a chatroom here or join one, then you can try doing that. I have seen such long discussions in comments get deleted

Comment: Thank you very much